# Android Camera 2 API without EXIF

Tags: android, android-camera, exif, android-camera2

I implemented a CameraActivity for the [Camera 2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html). But all photos I take have missing EXIF information, like geo-position.

It is not possible to get the photos GPS position by means of the ExifInterface. also when I open the photos on my desktop, no GPS properties were set. Photos taken by my Android device camera, has valid GPS position, etc.

**How can I take photos including their EXIF values?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But all photos I take have missing EXIF information, like geo-position.

Adding geo-position EXIF headers is not the job of the camera API. If you want location data, you need to obtain it yourself (e.g., via `LocationManager` and its requisite permissions), then add the EXIF headers that you want.